# Why is my 32 bit programs load in 3GB address space mode?

Tags: linux, 64bit, 32bit, elf

I have noticed, that Manjaro Linux (kernel 6.6.8) loads 32 bit executable files with ADDR_LIMIT_3GB set. Or as: `setarch -B --3g`.

But I have a clear memory, that earlier it was not the case and 32 bit programs started in --4G mode.

Is it hardcoded in the kernel or is configurable behavior? How to change it?

Comment: On what arch ? how did you notice ADDR_LIMIT_3GB is set ? what version of util-linux ?

Comment: additionally : running in some container ? seccomp ?

Comment: @MC68020: When I open the file in the debugger the stack is set at addresses under 0xc0000000. Also, sys_personality returns ADDR_LIMIT_3GB.